# Can someone help me with this permisson denied thing?

Tags: python

so I was trying to get bad apple on discord messages but I run into this error it keeps saying this.

[here is the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bDPk.png)

I do not know how to fix it and access is denied but i dont know how to fix it.

Comment: What is `frames`, where is it located, and where are you running your script from? That error is going to occur if you try to use `open()` on a directory.

Comment: im using a folder.

Comment: Add code and error messages as text, not image.